# baksmali Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION]

Tags: android

I use baksmail

```html
java -jar baksmali.jar -o classout/ classes.dex
```

and use

```html
java -jar smali.jar classout/ -o classes.dex
```

end,get the classes.dex back to apk,but cannot install ,here is the exception:INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION

Comment: why are you trying to build an APK from decompiled Android codes?